# Test if variable is a specific bound function in using javascript's Function.prototype.bind()

Tags: javascript, bind

I am trying to work out how to test if a variable is an instance of a specific bound function. Consider the following example:

```
var func = function( arg ) {
    // code here
}

myFunc = func.bind( null, 'val' );

if( myFunc == func ) {
    console.log( true );
} else {
    console.log( false );
}
```

Unfortunately this results in false. Is there some sort of way of testing the variable to find out what function it is bound to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is not a way to do this.  `.bind()` returns a new function that internally calls the original one.  There is no interface on that new function to retrieve the original one.

Per the [ECMAScript specification 15.3.4.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5), the returned "bound" function will have internal properties for `[[TargetFunction]]`, `[[BoundThis]]` and `[[BoundArgs]]`, but those properties are not public.

If you tell us what higher level problem you're trying to solve, we might be able to come up with a different type of solution.

---

If you yourself control the `.bind()` operation, you could put the original function on the bound function as a property and you could test that property:

```
var func = function( arg ) {
    // code here
}

myFunc = func.bind( null, 'val' );
myFunc.origFn = func;

if( myFunc === func || myFunc.origFn === func) {
    console.log( true );
} else {
    console.log( false );
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/e2gq6n8y/

You could even make your own `.bind()` replacement that did this automatically.

```
function bind2(fn) {
    // make copy of args and remove the fn argument
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    var b = fn.bind.apply(fn, args);
    b.origFn = fn;
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the technical specification details. So the new function provides no evidence that it is the result of a bind?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this directly because *functions*, just like *Objects*, have their equality tested by their reference which no longer matches, [**§11.9.3, point 1. f.**](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) or [**§11.9.6, point 7.**](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.6)

However, you could create some custom properties to test for, e.g.

```
function myBind(fn) { // takes 2+ args, the fn to bind, the new this, any other args
    var bind = Function.prototype.bind,
        bound = bind.call.apply(bind, arguments);
    bound.unbound = fn;
    return bound;
}
```

and then examle usage

```
function foo(bar) {
    console.log(this, bar);
}

// binding
var fizz = myBind(foo, {buzz:0}, 'baz');
fizz(); // logs {buzz: 0} "baz"

// testing
fizz.unbound === foo; // true
```

If you want to test in both directions, then you will need to *OR* them together, and perhaps even consider looping over these properties if you will be binding already bound functions

```
fizz.unbound === foo || fizz === foo.unbound; // true
```

---

Please also consider that the whole chain of unbound versions of the function will not be released from memory as long as a bound version exists, whereas some browsers would have been able to free this memory, depending on their implementation of `bind`

Comment: @jfriend00 Was going to just `.apply` and `.slice` out the function, but realised I didn't have to if I `.apply`ed `.call`, `bind.call.apply(bind, [x, y])`, we are `apply`ing `call`, the `this` of `call` is being set to `bind` (the first  `bind` is just a shortcut to it instead of `Function.prototype`ing). The first arg in `call` is `x`, which will be the `this` of `bind`, i.e. the function `bind` is supposed to be called on. The second arg in `call` will be the first arg in `bind`, i.e. the `this` value when the generated function is ultimately invoked.

Comment: Hmmm, OK.  So, you're purposely using `.apply()` on `.call()`.  Can't say I've ever seen that.

Answer (score 1):

Bind prepend "bound " before the source function's name.

If you can give a explicite name to the source function then you can do :

```
var func = function func( arg ) {
    // code here
}

var myFunc = func.bind( null, 'val' );


if( myFunc.name.match(/^(bound\ )*(.*)$/i)[2] === func.name ){

        console.log(true);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input @jfriend00 and @PaulS. I am using a function that automatically adds an unbound property to the bound function. Here is a refined version of what I wrote. Let me know what you think.

```
// My function
var myFunc = function() {
    return 'This is my function';
};

// Function I'm wrapping my function in
var wrapper = function( fn ) {

    var result;

    if( fn ) {
        result = fn.apply( null, arguments );
    }

    // Any additional logic I want to run after my function
    console.log( 'Ran wrapper logic' );

    return result;

};

// Modified binder method
var binder = function( fn, ths, args ) {

    args = [].concat( ths, args );

    var bound = fn.bind.apply( fn, args );

    bound.unbound = fn;

    return bound;

};

// Bind a wrapped version of my function 
myFunc = binder( wrapper, null, myFunc );

// I can test if my function has ben wrapped
console.log( myFunc.unbound == wrapper );

// And I can run a wrapped version of my function
console.log( myFunc() );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `instanceof` operator as long as your bound function is a constructable function and the variable you are testing is an instance of your constructable.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> When using a bound function as the right-hand side of instanceof,
> instanceof would reach for the target function (which is stored
> internally in the bound function) and read its prototype instead.

```
var func = function( arg ) {
    // code here
}

myFunc = func.bind( null, 'val' );

if( new func instanceof myFunc ) {
    console.log( true );
} else {
    console.log( false );
}
```

You simply have to write `func` so that it doesn't do anything unwanted when creating a new instance of it. For example if func doesn't need to construct:

```
var func = function( arg ) {
    if (this instanceof func) return;// do nothing
    // code here
}
```